# RegEx matching for URL redirect in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've some dynamic urls. If I took a url with a query parameter, it leads to 404 page. So I would like to do a redirection using htaccess. I tried with a matching url pattern regex and it is not redirecting.

Url structure will be `/detail/2019-12/news/news-title-12-2019.html?something` and which I need to redirect to `/detail/2019-12/news/news-title-12-2019.html`

I tried something like this, but it is not redirecting;

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^detail/\d{4}-\d{2}/news/(?=\S*['-])([a-zA-Z0-9'-]+\.html)\?\S*$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [NC,L,R=301]
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: RewriteRule matches against the path component of the URL only, if you want to check or match query string contents, you need to do so in a RewriteCond.

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/nwzkKt/1) might help you to write your RewriteRul:

```
^(.+\.html)(\?.+)$
```

[image]

I'm not quite sure, but your code might look like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^(.+\.html)(\?.+)$ http://domain_goes_here/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

---

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^(.+\.html)(\?.+)$ http://domain_goes_here/$1 [NC,L,R=302]
```

You also might need to:

- restart apache
- delete your browser cache

If you wish to add boundaries to your expression, [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/tbZar5/1) might help you to do so:

```
^(\/detail\/[0-9-]+\/news\/[a-z0-9-]+\.html)(\?.+)$
```

[image]

#### Code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^(\/detail\/[0-9-]+\/news\/[a-z0-9-]+\.html)(\?.+)$ http://domain_goes_here/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

---

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^(\/detail\/[0-9-]+\/news\/[a-z0-9-]+\.html)(\?.+)$ http://domain_goes_here/$1 [NC,L,R=302]
```

Comment: Hi Emma, thank you. But I need the url which should match the above format. I've some other URLs on the website which has parameter need to be maintained. I need to only remove the query string from the matching url pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you rule isn't working is because you are checking Querystring `?` in your rule regex. The pattern of RewriteRule is for URL path only .

The following should work for you

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^detail/\d{4}-\d{2}/news/ %{RRQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache or use a different browser for testing this.